# What's the optimal racetrack to use for the Rocket Manski achievement?

Tags: achievements, grid-2

The description for the *Rocket Manski* achievement reads as so:

> You've driven faster than a Russian torpedo, which incidentally is 230 mph (370 km/h).

I have yet to find a race track that lets me drive this fast before a shard corner or anything.

**What is the optimal track to drive on to obtain this achievement?

Should I also use a certain vehicle?**

Answer (score 4):

Yas Marina is the best track to do it, since it consist of the longest straights in the game. International GP Circuit is your best bet.

As for a car, you shoudl wait until you unlock something in Tier 4. I think that all cars from this tier can manage 370km/h. Koenigsegg is fastest of them all.